# JQuery function not executing inside a PHP loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a php array of result `$bank_r`. I want to perform some results in all of the results. For that I wrote :

```
$(function(){

//alert('<?php echo count($bank_r); ?> ');

    <?php

        for($i=0;$i<count($bank_r);$i++)
        {
           $bank_name = strtolower (str_replace(" ","",$bank_r[$i]['bank_name']));
        ?>
        alert('<?php echo $bank_name; ?>');
        <?php } ?>

-------------
----------
//Some other jquery functions
//
//
});
```

I was expecting to alert the `$bank_name`, but it is not. Even the top `alert('<?php echo count($bank_r); ?> ');` also not alerting anything. But If I remove the `php for loop`, the top `alert` alerts the number of results. Whats wrong ?

EDIT:
Generated javascript code:

```
    <script>

    $(function(){

    //alert('5 ');

                alert('ucobank
    ');
                    alert('pnb');
                    alert('bob');
                    alert('sbi');
                    alert('hdfc');
//Other javascripts
});
```

Comment: Can you look into browser console? Are there any errors?

Comment: Have you checked the console (`F12`) for errors?

Comment: Don't say that JavaScript doesn't work and show us PHP. Show us the generated JavaScript (and if you are generating JavaScript that doesn't match what you think it should be: Show us the PHP as well and ask a question about why its output differs from what you expect).

Comment: Why is your alert($bank_r) commented out?

Comment: It is inside the `php` page, within `<script></script>` @swapnesh

Comment: @user2629220 why dont you `echo $bank_name` to check what is pouring in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($bank_r);$i++)
{
   $bank_name = strtolower (str_replace(" ","",$bank_r[$i]['bank_name']));
   echo '<script> alert("'.$bank_name.'");</script>';
   // if you are outside the javascript then use script tag, otherwise remove the tags
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

New line in first alert is problem. It causes JS parse error and because of that alerts will not appear. You have to replace newline to eg. spaces by `str_replace("\n", ' ', $string);`.